# Is it possible to share image AND text (so both together) in Flutter? i tried with share_plus and is only working for Android

Tags: android, ios, flutter, share, share-plus

i'm trying to share content ( image + text + URL) from Flutter app (IOS and Android) to Linkedin and WhatsApp. Currently with share_plus is working fine on WhatsApp for Android. i couldn't find a solution for IOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there’s restrictions from WhatsApp side.

take a look at this [issue](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/issues/261)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, i saw it. i thought that could be a way to share it as long as for Android is working as expected. Linkedin doesn't work either

Comment: Yes, and I think facebook too have some restrictions too, you can only share links I guess

Comment: If you find this answer useful, please if you don't mind select it as the best answer.